# Cannot insert variable into path for Get-Item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to take a list of strings separated by a return and split them by the `=` symbol, both sides match a registry key which is queried by Get-Item. The first half always matches fine, but referencing the second half only matches for the last item in the list:

First half example:

```
[string[]]$Patch = (".accda=Access.ACCDAExtension.16
.accdb=Access.Application.16" -split "`n")

Foreach ($a in $Patch) {
    $RegKey = ($a -split "=")[0]
    $Result = Get-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$RegKey"
    echo $Result
}
```

This returns:

```
Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                                                    
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                                                    
.accda                         (default)    : Access.ACCDAExtension.16                                                                                                                                                     
                               Content Type : application/msaccess.addin                                                                                                                                                   
.accdb                         (default)    : Access.Application.16                                                                                                                                                        
                               Content Type : application/msaccess
```

Second half example:

```
[string[]]$Patch = ("
.accda=Access.ACCDAExtension.16
.accdb=Access.Application.16
" -split "`n")

Foreach ($a in $Patch) {
    $RegKey = ($a -split "=")[1]
    $Result = Get-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$RegKey"
}
```

This returns:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCDAExtension.16' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:15
+     $Result = Get-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$RegKey"
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_CLASSES_RO...DAExtension.16:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand



    Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                                                    
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                                                    
Access.Application.16          (default) : Microsoft Access Database
```

However, that registry key does exist and if I run the command manually it finds it:

```
get-item Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCDAExtension.16


    Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                                                    
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                                                    
Access.ACCDAExtension.16       (default) : Microsoft Access Add-in
```

I'm pretty sure it's caused by the return at the end of each line.

---

PowerShell version 5.1

Comment: I tried it real quick but it does not give me an error and executes just fine. What PS version are you using?

Comment: Not sure but have a try using Join-Path `Join-Path "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" "txtfile"`

Comment: The command you've posted by itself does not explain your symptom, in any PowerShell version. Please update  your question with additional information that may be required to narrow the problem down.

Comment: @AimusSage I'm running version 5.1

Comment: Is there anything else you do between setting `$RegKey` and calling `Get-Item`?

Comment: @AimusSage I apologise, the issue is almost definitely caused by the way I'm manipulating my list in my real script, I have modified the question to include a proper example of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
[string[]]$Patch = ("
.accda=Access.ACCDAExtension.16
.accdb=Access.Application.16
" -split "`n")
```

to this

```
[string[]]$Patch = (-split "
.accda=Access.ACCDAExtension.16
.accdb=Access.Application.16
")
```

That way you don't have any whitespaces.

[Here is some more background on the split operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this my making my list a list of strings:

```
[string[]]$Patch = (".accda=Access.ACCDAExtension.16",
".accdb=Access.Application.16" -split "`n")

Foreach ($a in $Patch) {
    $RegKey = ($a -split "=")[1]
    $Result = Get-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$RegKey"
}
```

The issue was probably caused by the return at the end of each line, maybe I could have also filtered it out of the command.